# Java project structure at the granular level

Tags: java, class, oop, package

I am curious about java project structure, as well as best practices in regards to classes, interfaces, etc.

If anyone knows of a good open source project that follows good best practices I would appreciate it; it seems like every one is slightly different, with some downright contradicting Oracle documentation on the topic. If anyone could give me a breakdown (or a critique of my structure for a theoretical project it would be appreicated). I understand the /src, bin, lib, doc, etc. as well as com.* structure reasonably well I believe. My issue is exactly WHAT should be in each class, in each file, etc.

My biggest issue is how to exactly break up functionality between classes. For example; I have two classes:

Person.java
Runner.java (This is entry point; is there a naming convention for the entry points? It also seems that classes with main(), run(), etc. are a different 'tier'....how to decide where the entry point should be? Should a class with only main () be made (as well as the actual execution of necessary calculations?)

Person has all the the common variables you would expect....

```
int height, weight;
String ethnicity;
boolean gender; etc.etc.
Person(int h, int w.....) {this.height=h....}
public getters/setters for all variables
```

Now I am looking for a program that will do two things:

- Take all the attributes of every Person (Say we have instantiated an array of Person()), concatanate them to a String and add that to a new Array.
- Order the people by height, then weight, and put into a List.

So for the first thing; should Person class have a method "String concatToString(){}", or should the code that does the concatanetion be in Runner...for example:

Runner.java:

```
public class Runner {

String getPersonString(Person p) {
   StringBuffer Sb = new StringBuffer();
   Sb.append(p.get(height));
   etc.
   return Sb.toString();
}

main() {
   for(int i=0; i<arr.len; i++) {
       getPersonString(arr[i]);
   }

   //more code that we will be further executing etc...; mostly just function calls in
   class Runner
}
}
```

Now for the second problem how should I approach this...create a new class; create a priorityQueue and comparator in runner.java? Create another class PersonPQueue that has the comparator in it?

These issues consistently pop up in my code and I am never certain how to split my code correctly. Any great and clear examples would be much appreciated. I have checked out some open source projects and many were too large for me to wrap my head around the design decisions in a reasonable amount of time or had contradictory design choices.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot going on in your posting.  It's a huge topic for a Q&A site.  Anyway, I'll answer some specific points.

> Take all the attributes of every Person (Say we have instantiated an
>   array of Person()), concatanate them to a String and add that to a new
>   Array.

Implement `toString()` in your `Person` class, that formats a Person in a certain way.  The thing that calls `toString()` would probably not be in the `Person` class.  Without more context, I can't say for sure.

> Order the people by height, then weight, and put into a List.

If this were to be the only way to sort `Person`, I'd make the getter for the sorted list a method in `Person` and add the `Comparator` class to the bottom of the `Person` class.  If the application gets more complex, where several sorts could be used, I'd consider moving the `Comparator`s to their own class files.

My final advice would be to not sweat it too much and to do it the easiest/quickest way.  The reason is that many of these decisions are arbitrary and don't really matter in the scheme of things.

I would avoid making the `Person.PersonComparator` class public outside of `Person`.  The reason is that if something changes and you decide the comparators should be outside of `Person`, you could eventually have applications out there referring to the internals of `Person`.  Now when you want to re-org `Person`, a bunch of code has to be changed.  What a pain!

What you have to do is to understand the business and their needs going forward.  If they are not sure how to sort `Person` then program defensively, perhaps, and put the comparators outside of it.  Or implement an Interface or Facade design pattern to further insulate your code from the fickleness of the users.  For items that are well defined, do the easiest thing. This affords more time for testing, reduces unhelpful unneeded abstractions, and increases the chance of project success.

Comment: Thanks for the response!. So if I were to place the comparator in Person.java; I should probably put Person in a seperate package to limit the access only to person, correct?

Also, do you have any insight on the class that includes main()? Should main be its only method? Where in the package structure should it be.

Comment: I would put all the files related to this project into the same package.  I never use package-level security.  Everything is public, or private.  Use sub-packages for very distinct facilities.  For example, I could see `com.dax.myprogram` for the main classes like `Person` and `com.dax.myprogram.reports` for classes related to the project's reporting. If you decided to add a webservice, that code could be in `com.gax.myprogram.ws`.  But if there's one report and one web service, you might dump it all into `com.dax.myproject` anyway.

Comment: Regarding the "main" question, I would make it a separate class.